# Jquery: Hide all children, then show a specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show

I want to hide all child elements in a div.
And then show a specific one passed on to the function.

```
function subDisplay(name) {
   $("#navSub").each(function() {
      $(this).hide();
   });
   $(name).show();
}
```

then i call the function from an onmouse event like: `subDisplay(#DivIwantToShow);`
But nothing displays...

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is passed in `name`? Is it a jQuery object, or a selector? Also, looking at your code it appears you have more than one `#navSub`, which is illegal HTML - you can only have one unique ID in the page - use classes instead.

Comment: are you literally calling `subDisplay(#DivIwantToShow);`?

Comment: You need `subDisplay('#DivIwantToShow');` -- it's a string that you pass there

Comment: FYI, you can optimize your code by calling `$('#navSub').hide()`, rather than iterating over them using `each()`

Comment: Are you actually using `subDisplay(#DivIWantToShow)` or are you using `subDisplay("#DivIWantToShow")`?

Also, what happens if, in subDisplay, you `console.log(name)`?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You need to hide the children and not the containing div.

`$("#navSub").children().hide();`

So now if the div you are trying to show is an element in the parent div it will still show while the others stay hidden.

Comment: Pretty simple and good, however, I would like to add that you can use toggle() for ease of life

Answer (score 5):

If you're targeting the children of `#navSub`, you need target them and hide *them*, rather than the element `navSub`; which you can do using the [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children) method;

```
function subDisplay(name) {
    $('#navSub').children().hide();
    $(name).show();
};
```

Otherwise, it appears you have multiple elements with the same ID in your DOM, which is not allowed.

You then need to pass a string (which is a valid jQuery selector) to `subDisplay()`;

```
subDisplay('#DivIwantToShow');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function subDisplay(name) {
   $("#navSub").hide();
   $('#'+name).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the great comments from @dotweb and @Matt;

```
function subDisplay(name) {
   $('#navSub').hide();
   $(name).show();
}

subDisplay('#DivIwantToShow');
```

Answer (score 1):

if the name of the element is passed in name use this:

```
    if($(this).attr('name') != name){
    //Hide it
    } else {
   //show it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try having it outside of the loop, like so:

```
function subDisplay(name) {

     $("#navSub").hide();

     $(name).show();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/peduarte/m2pj8/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide **child div** using **class**.

```
<div class="parent_div">
    <div class="child_div">1st div</div>
    <div class="child_div">2nd div</div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".parent_div").on('click',function(){
        $j(this).find("div").toggle();
    })
})
```